# Why do I get a “Only variables should be assigned by reference” error with this PHP code?

Tags: php

I get this error:

> Only variables should be assigned by reference

on this line:

```
$sum = &self::genchksum10($isbn);
```

of my function:

```
public function validateten($isbn) {
        $isbn = trim($isbn);
        $chksum = substr($isbn, -1, 1);
        $isbn = substr($isbn, 0, -1);
        if (preg_match('/X/i', $chksum)) { $chksum="10"; }
        $sum = &self::genchksum10($isbn);
        if ($chksum == $sum){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I’m not really sure what’s wrong with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the '&' in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

An object cannot reference itself with a reference (`&`).

Try without it:

```
 $sum = self::genchksum10($isbn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a reference to the result of a function. That's not possible in PHP.

Just remove the `&`